# Can I write log output of my choice from the Apache configuration (based on rewrite conditions)?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, logging, geolocation

I have some content that is only available to people who pass a GeoIP lookup and match certain countries.  This is done by mod_rewrite and it all works well.

What I would like to do is log failed attempts, to help debug people who should be able to get at this content but cannot.  In order to do this at present I need RewriteLogLevel at 4, which means everything on the virtual host is logged, rather than just the stuff I am restricting.

This is the example from the mod_geoip readme:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|css)$ - [L] # don't redirect images and stylesheets
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.canada.com [L] # redirect everything else
```

I would like to add something like

```
WriteThisToLog "Denied access to $1 from IP $2 due to calculated country $3"
```

The variables are all there - is there a directive I can use to write out to the Apache error log?

**Edit:** I would have put this in the comment to the correct answer, but formatting was important.  I've ended up with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.canada.com [L,E=GEOIP_FAIL:1] # redirect everything else
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE=%{GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}e" geoip_fail_format
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/geoip_fail_log geoip_fail_format env=GEOIP_FAIL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module called [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html) which has directives called [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) and [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat). Basically we define a output format using LogFormat and redirect it to the file mentioned in CustomLog.

Comment: Thanks: I'll update the question with what I actually did.